# spring cloud contract - tour - request body issue

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to understand spring cloud contract so am reading the tour.
My question is specifically regarding this section:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_verifier_introduction.html#_defining_the_contract

Looking at the **request body** part, there is a difference between the Groovy and YAML contracts.
In the Groovy DSL:

> "client.id": $(regex('[0-9]{10}'))

In the YAML:

> "client.id": 1234567890

You can see the difference - one is specific, the other is not.

Questions are:
Q1. Is this difference deliberate?
Q2. Is it correct that these are turned into tests on the Producer side, so they are run against my real implementation of the service?
So does that mean my real implementation needs to support the hard coded client.id of 1234567890?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is such that in Groovy DSL we can code sth and YAML is just declarative. In Groovy, in the body, we can state that the value of a particular part of the body will be dynamic. Then at runtime we will generate the fixed value (e.g. for the generated tests). You could also achieve the same via the `bodyMatchers` section.

In Yaml however you can't code. You need to provide a fixed value and if you want to have a dynamic part of that particular e.g. body element then you have to provide that value in the matchers sections. That will tell the framework that there is a fixed value for e.g. generated tests BUT also there's a dynamic part to consider e.g. for the stub.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So the difference is deliberate? (maybe worth calling it out in the tour?)

Comment: And please could you directly answer Q2? Is this turned into tests on the Producer side, and does my real service implementation need to handle the client.id of 1234567890?
Also, in the Groovy DSL scenario, you say a client.id value is generated - from the regex?
I am rather new to this and finding it rather confusing

Comment: >  Q2. Is it correct that these are turned into tests on the Producer side, so they are run against my real implementation of the service?

correct. All of your questions are answered in the documentation of the project. Please read it https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract#learn

Comment: Thanks. I have been reading that, yes.
Final question if you'll indulge me please: Are the generated Producer tests also run against the generated wiremocked service? I do not think they are, as both are generated from the same contract so it would be somewhat pointless anyway, but I would like to double check.

Comment: No they're not. Can we mark this as answered please?